# How to make Combine.Zip work with failure and success of two `Publishers`

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I'm trying to make `Zip` two `Publishers` with two different functions, but it's not working as expected. I have a chance to one may failure and one success. but even one is successful I'm not getting a successful response in the `sink`. Here is my code, help is greatly appreciated.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var buttonTapped = false
    @State var cancellable = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    var body: some View {
        Group {
           Text("Home")
        }.onAppear {
            Publishers.Zip(fetchData1(), fetchData2())
                .sink(receiveCompletion: { first in
                switch first {
                case .failure(let er):
                    print(er)
                case .finished:
                    print("ss")
                }
            }, receiveValue: { (a, b) in
               print(a, b)
             // Not printing success value
            }).store(in: &cancellable)
        }
    }

    func fetchData1() -> Future<Bool, ErrorType> {
        return Future { promise in
            promise(.failure(.error("fetchData1 failed")))
        }
    }
    
    func fetchData2() -> Future<String, ErrorType> {
        return Future { promise in
            promise(.success("fetchData success "))
        }
    }
}

enum ErrorType: Error {
    case error(String)
}
```

Comment: What is it that you are actually trying to achieve? `Zip` only emits value N when __both__ of its values emitted for the N-th time. So if both of its upstreams complete N elements, then one completes, then `Zip` itself completes as well without waiting for more elements. This means that if you `Zip` 2 `Future`s, one of which fails, `Zip` cannot emit any elements, since one of its upstreams failed without emitting any values. `Zip` is not the operator you are looking for, however, without knowing what actual problem you are trying to solve, it's hard to tell which operator you actually need.

Comment: @Dávid Pásztor thanks for your comment, If I know why would I post here?  tell me if you could how can I handle my case. I'm just started with combine.

Comment: That is the problem, you didn't explain what is _your case_. You've just shown that something doesn't work as expected. Please explain the actual problem that you are trying to solve. You are trying to combine 2 `Publisher`s, but what should be the behaviour if either of them fails? Do you still want the value from the other? When do you want to receive the value, as soon as either of them emitted it or only after both did?

Comment: I have two different requirements, `Case: 1` If the first request fails don't proceed next request. `Case: 2` Even 1 failed to continue to the second request handle in case of any errors of both. I'm confused between these two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a playground that demonstrates each case.

It includes a function `makeRequest` that creates a `Future` to simulate a request that either succeeds or fails.

At the heart of the sample is a pattern:

```
someFailableRequest
  .tryMap { return a value indicating success or failure }
  .catch { _ in Just(a value indicating success or failure) }
```

if the request succeeds, the value we pass to later stages indicates success.  If it fails, then `catch` returns a publisher that generates the same kind of thing, but indicating failure.

That pattern is used recursively to handle each case in a slightly different way.

```
import Cocoa
import Combine
import Foundation

func makeRequest(shouldFail: Bool) -> AnyPublisher<String, Error> {
    return Future<String, Error> { fulfill in
        let delay = (100...500).randomElement()!
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).asyncAfter(
            deadline: .now() + DispatchTimeInterval.milliseconds(delay)) {
                if shouldFail {
                    fulfill(.failure(NSError(domain: "sadness", code: -1)))
                } else {
                    fulfill(.success("Yea!"))
                }
            }
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

// Case 1.  First request fails, don't do second one
let request1 = makeRequest(shouldFail: true)
let request2 = makeRequest(shouldFail: false)

let requestChain = request1
    .tryMap { return $0 as String? }
    .catch { _ in return Just(nil as String?) }
    .flatMap { (firstResult: String?) -> AnyPublisher<(String?, String?), Never> in
        if firstResult != nil {
            return request2
                .tryMap { result2 in (firstResult, result2) }
                .catch { _ in Just((firstResult, nil)) }
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        } else {
            return Just((nil as String?, nil as String?)).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
    }

let cancellable = requestChain.sink { debugPrint("first chain \($0)") }

// Case2 : continue second request even if first fails.

let request3 = makeRequest(shouldFail: true)
let request4 = makeRequest(shouldFail: false)

let requestChain1 =
    request3
    .tryMap { firstResult -> AnyPublisher<(String?,String?),Never> in
        request4
            .tryMap { secondResult in (firstResult, secondResult) }
            .catch { _ in Just( (firstResult as String?, nil) ).eraseToAnyPublisher() }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    .catch { _ in
        Just(request4
            .tryMap { secondResult in (nil as String?, secondResult) }
            .catch { _ in Just( (nil as String?, nil as String?) ) }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher())
    }
    .flatMap { $0 }


let cancellable2 = requestChain1.sink { debugPrint("second chain \($0)") }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good. Not sure your requirement, but it works this way,

- either of them fail, all fail
- only two succeed, it succeeds
- I was guessing we can't get one data if the other fails

Check out the [doc from apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/zip):
Use Publishers.Zip to combine the latest elements from two publishers and emit a tuple to the downstream. The returned publisher waits until both publishers have emitted an event, then delivers the oldest unconsumed event from each publisher together as a tuple to the subscriber.